# Host name changes to local host when queued jobs get executed (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am running my project using homestead and Laravel 5.2. I reach the app by below link:

```
http://XXXXXX.dev/
```

Some emails pushed to queue by using database driver but after running emails, host for images and even links chege to `localhost`.

Here is my env settings:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_TYPE=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
```

Must be said that without using queue and jobs it works fine.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `APP_URL` to `http://XXXXXX.dev/` but I did not see any changes in the results, finally I realised after changing code `app artisan queue:listen` must be run again. So it could execute the new code.